# Braintree server_side integration on android

Tags: android, paypal, braintree

I need help integrating the server-side part of Braintree SDK in order to accept payments using Paypal.

I am trying to use the PHP integration from this [link](https://inducesmile.com/android/using-braintree-payment-in-android-to-accept-payment/)

```
<?php
include_once 'braintree-php-3.21.1/lib/Braintree.php';
Braintree_Configuration::environment('sandbox');
Braintree_Configuration::merchantId(' ');
Braintree_Configuration::publicKey(' ');
Braintree_Configuration::privateKey(' ');
if(isset($_POST["NONCE"])){
  $nonceFromTheClient = $_POST["NONCE"];
  $result = Braintree_Transaction::sale([
    'amount' => '1000.00',
    'paymentMethodNonce' => $nonceFromTheClient,
    'options' => ['submitForSettlement' => true ]
  ]);
  if ($result->success) {
      echo("success!: " . $result->transaction->id);
  } else if ($result->transaction) {
      echo "Error processing transaction: \n" . " code: " . $result->transaction->processorResponseCode . " \n " . " text: " . $result->transaction->processorResponseText;
  } else {
      echo "Validation errors: \n"; //+ $result->errors->deepAll();
  }
}else{
  echo($clientToken = Braintree_ClientToken::generate());
}
?>
```

But i keep getting this error
[IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WtC8u.png)

I am not excperienced in creating web apps, but It's a most and the braintree's docs are not detailed enough.

If there is any sample i can use, in any other language it's fine by me.

Comment: Your Braintree_Configuration lines look to contain empty strings.  Is this how it's been implemented or did you remove them for this post?

See format at https://developers.braintreepayments.com/start/hello-server/php#install-and-configure

Comment: Yes I have removed the for the post only, I have them implemented.

Comment: Based on the error, it's not finding the file (braintree-php-3.21.1/lib/Braintree.php) in the first place.  This could be due to a bad path or that file not existing.  Can you double check? 

Also, I would recommend using `require_once` instead of `include_once`, as `require` would have thrown an error instead of warning for this missing file.

https://github.braintreeps.com/braintree/braintree-php#quick-start-example, If you are using composer with --classmap-authoritative or --optimize-autoloader enabled, you'll have to reference classes using PSR-4 namespacing (see example at that link)